# I am getting A RenderFlex overflowed by 57 pixels on the bottom

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Hi I am new to Flutter and I came across this error that is in the title I looked here as well but nothing seems to help, the layout looks just fine when I star the app however I am getting an error which drives me crazy. One of the solutions that I found was to add  resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false which I did but the error is still present.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
  body: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              flex: 3,
              child: SizedBox(),
            ),
            _title(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 50,
            ),
            _displayUserNameAndPassword(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            _submitButton(),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              child: Text('Forgot Password ?',
                  style:
                      TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
            ),
            _divider(),
            _facebookButton(),
            Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: SizedBox(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child:  _createAccountLabel(),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: You need to wrap your `Stack` into `ListView` with `shrinkWrap` set to `true`, The concept of `flex` is to give them all `flex` value.

Comment: What happens when you change `Column` to `ListView`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ListView instead of Column.
In column when keyboard appears for text field it caused renderflexed overflow error.
Thanks